# How to create dynamic URL for blog in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and I am creating a personal blog. I have done the UI part and I am displaying 260 chars from the article-content.

Where I'm stuck:

When the user click on the article's title, it should go to the page with the URL (E.g.: `example.com/title-one`). But, I don't know how to fetch the corresponding Content of that title. Both title and content are in the same table coupled with ID.

How can I pass the ID and use that to fetch Content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating a post, you can add a field for your slug. Some `varchar` column would fit. Every slug has to be unique, so you can find the article in your database.

For creating slugs with CI, I would recommend this:

In the [url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) you have a method called `url_title`. Just pass the articles title:

```
$slug = url_title($title, '_', TRUE);
```

Then save it with your additional data to the database.

When you are viewing an article. Do something like this:

```
$slug = $this->uri->segment(n);//change it to fit;
```

In your fetching model method for viewing an article, just find the article by the given slug.

```
$this->db->get_where('your_articles_table', array('slug' => $slug));
```

Also you can add some additional routing, to perfectly fit your needs.